# feed helper from a callback

Tags: meteor

I am trying to implement a file browser in Meteor. Users can go through some network folders and add them to the collection for further processing.

This is my simple template displaying ".." and folders from a given directory

```
<template name="folderBrowser">
  <ul>
    <li class="js-browseUp">..</li>
    {{#each folder}}
    <li class="js-selectFolder">{{.}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

A server method to get folder content

```
'displayFolderContent'(folderName) {
    var folders = fs.readdirSync(folderName)
    console.log(folderName +':'+ folders);
    return folders;
}
```

And my attempt (not working). I believe I am passing a function to the helper and the method is asynchronous so I can't pass "d" directly, but can't figure out, how to solve this.

```
Template.folderBrowser.helpers({
  folder: function() {
    Meteor.call('displayFolderContent', myFolder, function(e, d) {
      console.log(d); // logs an array of folder content correctly into browser console
      return d;
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it is a good idea using a Meteor method in a template helper.

A simple solution would be to use an intermediate `ReactiveVar`. When your template is created, make your method call, and update the `ReactiveVar` in the callback. Then in your `folder` helper, simply return the `ReactiveVar` content.

Meteor will update reactively when your method asynchronously returns.

Comment: agreed, it is definitely not a good idea to call a method from a helper. OP, this is the correct solution.

Comment: I got to that point a few hours later too. I am using ReactiveVar and some ReactiveArray package. Works great!