# Displaying cursor data within a blaze template does not work with Meteor.call()

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

ı have a very simple template as follows;

```
<template name="editingUsers">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <ul class="custom-list-stye">
                {{#each lastEditors}}
                    <li><span><strong>{{docUser.name}}</strong></span> </li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I am filling the list in the HTML with an helper;

```
Template.editingUsers.helpers({
    lastEditors:  function () {
        return Meteor.call('getLastEditors');
    }
});
```

The 'getLastEditors' method returns data by a MongoDB query;

```
getLastEditors: function () {
        if(Meteor.user()) {
            const lastEditors = Documents.find(
                {docUser: {$exists: true }},
                {
                    limit:5,
                    sort: { lastEdit: -1 },
                });
            return lastEditors;
        }
    }
```

With this code, the data that should be displayed as a list does not appear. however if I make the Mongo DB query directly from the helper everything becomes OK. The following is the working helper code. (The autopublish package is not removed)

```
Template.editingUsers.helpers({
    lastEditors:  function () {
        return Documents.find(
            {docUser: {$exists: true }},
            {
                limit:5,
                sort: { lastEdit: -1 },
            });
    }
});
```

As you know, ı cannot continue with autopublish package and I have to implement Meteor.methods(). I don't understand why returning cursor data from Meteor.method is not shown within the template. Can I have your comments please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to replace the `autopublish` package is to implement the [Publish and Subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html) pattern (which is what `autopublish` does under the hood), not to use Meteor methods.

Your last code example (where you search your `Documents` collection directly in the Client template helper) is perfectly fine. You just need to setup a Publish on your server with at least those documents (you can publish even more if necessary), and Subscribe to it, typically when your template is created.

As a short term workaround, you could use an intermediate `ReactiveVar` to display your cursor in your template helper.

See [feed helper from a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460764/feed-helper-from-a-callback)

Furthermore, on your Client you have to use `Meteor.call` with a callback. It does not return anything.

See http://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-call

Comment: Thanks @ghybs for your comment!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! If the answer did solve your issue or provided significant help, the SO way to thank people is also to _accept_ the answer.